# What is the use of for in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not understanding what for in doing in the code below can someone help me.

```
s = ' Abs3 asdasd asd11 111 11ss'

alpha_count = 0
digit_count = 0
for c in s:    ## here we are looping over every character in the string
    if c.isalpha():
        alpha_count += 1
    elif c.isdigit():
        digit_count += 1

print(alpha_count, digit_count)

(14,8)
```

Comment: It splits the string s into individual characters and looks at each one in turn.

Comment: The comment in the code describes what it's doing. What more are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` is used to loop through the defined variable `s`, which in this case is a string containing letters, digits (numbers), and whitespace (spaces, tabs etc.).

First time:

```
' Abs3 asdasd asd11 111 11ss'
 ^
```

As we can see, the first character of the string is: "" (space).
The code goes on to test if "" is a letter (`isalpha`) or if it is a digit (`isdigit`). In this first case, it is neither and the `for` loop continues with the next character:

```
' Abs3 asdasd asd11 111 11ss'
  ^
```

Second character is "`A`". In this case, the if statement results in `alpha_count += 1`. In other words: The string contains 1 letter.

Third time the `for` is looped:

```
' Abs3 asdasd asd11 111 11ss'
   ^
```

… is a letter. Thus: `alpha_count += 1` = `2`.

The for statement loops through the whole string before revealing that the string contains: 14 letters and 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` splits every character in `s` and loops over them. In each iteration  checks if it's alpha and adds 1 to the alpha count or if it's digit and adds 1 to the digit count.

Eventually, it will show how many alphabetic character your string has along with how many digits.

Answer (score 0):

`for in` iterates over the items of every sequence (a string or a list etc.) in the order that they appear in the sequence.

Example:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for num in nums:
  print(num*num]
```

this prints:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Example#02:

```
text = 'Python is Fun.!'
for ch in text:
  print(ch.upper())
```

this prints:

```
P
Y
T
H
O
N

I
S

F
U
N
.
!
```

As far as your code is concerned:

`for in` loop iterates over every single character of the string and checks if it is an alphabet or digit.

Answer (score 0):

In python, **Strings are iterable**, and you can iterate over a string. In your example, we can see what happens to `c` in each iteration (let us look at part of it):

```
s = ' Abs3 asdasd'
for c in s:
    print(f'c is {c}')
```

results in:

```
c is  
c is A
c is b
c is s
c is 3
c is  
c is a
c is s
c is d
c is a
c is s
c is d
```